# Archivo .gitignore añadir carpeta (phpstorm + windows + laravel)

Tags: laravel, windows, git, phpstorm, gitignore

Tengo un fichero `.gitignore` con el siguiente contenido. Lo he creado mediante la web [gitignore.io](http://gitignore.io/) y le puse los tags de `windows`, `phpstorm` y `laravel` ya que voy a programar con el editor mediante [phpstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/), bajo la plataforma windows y con el framework laravel.

Tengo un problema con la carpeta **.idea** de un proyecto en laravel que he empezado, ya que GIT todo el rato me detecta cambios en esos ficheros.

Por lo tanto mi pregunta es cómo puedo bien IGNORAR esos ficheros mediante alguna instrucción de git o bien como hacer para que el archivo .gitignore sea efectivo con esos ficheros.

```
# Created by https://www.gitignore.io/api/laravel,windows,phpstorm
# Edit at https://www.gitignore.io/?templates=laravel,windows,phpstorm

### Laravel ###
/vendor/
node_modules/
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log

# Laravel 4 specific
bootstrap/compiled.php
app/storage/

# Laravel 5 & Lumen specific
public/storage
public/hot
storage/*.key
.env
Homestead.yaml
Homestead.json
/.vagrant
.phpunit.result.cache

### PhpStorm ###
# Covers JetBrains IDEs: IntelliJ, RubyMine, PhpStorm, AppCode, PyCharm, CLion, Android Studio and WebStorm
# Reference: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839

# User-specific stuff
.idea/

# CMake
cmake-build-*/

# File-based project format
*.iws

# IntelliJ
out/

# mpeltonen/sbt-idea plugin
.idea_modules/

# JIRA plugin
atlassian-ide-plugin.xml

# Cursive Clojure plugin
.idea/replstate.xml

# Crashlytics plugin (for Android Studio and IntelliJ)
com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml
crashlytics.properties
crashlytics-build.properties
fabric.properties

# Editor-based Rest Client
.idea/httpRequests

# Android studio 3.1+ serialized cache file
.idea/caches/build_file_checksums.ser

### PhpStorm Patch ###
# Comment Reason: https://github.com/joeblau/gitignore.io/issues/186#issuecomment-215987721

# *.iml
# modules.xml
# .idea/misc.xml
# *.ipr

# Sonarlint plugin
.idea/**/sonarlint/

# SonarQube Plugin
.idea/**/sonarIssues.xml

# Markdown Navigator plugin
.idea/**/markdown-navigator.xml
.idea/**/markdown-navigator/

### Windows ###
# Windows thumbnail cache files
Thumbs.db
Thumbs.db:encryptable
ehthumbs.db
ehthumbs_vista.db

# Dump file
*.stackdump

# Folder config file
[Dd]esktop.ini

# Recycle Bin used on file shares
$RECYCLE.BIN/

# Windows Installer files
*.cab
*.msi
*.msix
*.msm
*.msp

# Windows shortcuts
*.lnk

# End of https://www.gitignore.io/api/laravel,windows,phpstorm
```

Gracias,

Comment: En principio se ve que tu .gitignore contiene la carpeta .idea, lo que pasa es que si esa carpeta ya está comiteada en tu repositorio, .gitignore no va a hacer nada. .gitignore solo ignora archivos que aún no forman parte del repositorio. Para solucionarlo puedes hacerte un backup de .idea, borrar la carpeta, commitear el borrado y restaurar la carpeta. En principio así no te debería salir como diferencias cuando hagas git status.

Comment: gracias @ordago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno para phpstorm normalmente yo ignoro toda la carpeta:

```
# --- IDE'S ---
.idea/
```

Ahora bien si no quieres ponerlo asi podrias probar lo siguiente para que el gitignore agarre los cambios correctamente:

```
git rm --cached .gitignore
```

Este comando te servirá siempre que adiciones una carpeta en tu `.gitignore`, puedes encontrar mas información [en éste enlace](http://www.codeblocq.com/2016/01/Untrack-files-already-added-to-git-repository-based-on-gitignore/)

Espero te sea de ayuda ;) Saludos

Comment: muchas gracias @Isarel-ICM con esto lo solucioné. 1000 gracias